# What are Definition, Algorithms and Practical Solutions for Concave Hull?

Tags: geometry, convex-hull, algorithm, concave-hull, gis-principle

#### Convex Hull

A convex hull of a shape is defined as:

> In mathematics, the convex hull or convex envelope for a set of points X in a real vector space V is the minimal convex set containing X ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull))

Wikipedia visualizes it nicely using a rubber band analogy, and there are some [good algorithms to compute it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms).

#### Concave Hull

A concave hull is visualized using the red line in the image below (the blue line visualizes the convex hull). Intuitively, it is a polygon which embraces all the points, but has less (minimal?) area compared to the convex hull. As a result, the polygon's boundary length is longer.

A concave hull may be the solution for some real-world problems (e.g. finding the reasonable boundary of a city).

[image]

Is there a proper definition, algorithm and practical solution for the notion of a Concave Hull?

The [Grass Wiki has some descriptions and images](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Create_concave_hull), and there is a commercial solution in [concavehull.com](http://www.concavehull.com/).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

As [scw points out](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/concave-hull-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions/1202#1202), you want an implementation of [α-shapes](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs268-14-fall/Handouts/AlphaShapes/2010-B-01-AlphaShapes.pdf).

Alpha shapes can be considered a generalisation of the convex hull.  They were first described in 1981 in:

> Edelsbrunner, H.; Kirkpatrick, D.;
> Seidel, R.; , "On the shape of a set
> of points in the plane," Information
> Theory, IEEE Transactions on  ,
> vol.29, no.4, pp. 551- 559, Jul 1983

Open source implementations exist for the environments you are interested in:

### PostGIS

If you are using the PostGIS stack, [pgRouting](http://pgrouting.postlbs.org/)'s optional [Driving Distance extension](http://pgrouting.postlbs.org/wiki/DrivingDistance) exposes an alpha shape implementation.  I'm not sure if you can vary the alpha parameter, however.

Usage is below:

```
SELECT the_geom AS alpha_shape 
FROM 
  points_as_polygon(
    'SELECT id, ST_X(your_geom) AS x, ST_Y(your_geom) AS y FROM your_table');
```

### Python

There are probably many Python modules you could use.  I have heard good things about [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org), a C++ computational geometry library. [Python wrappers](http://cgal-python.gforge.inria.fr/) exist for parts of CGAL, including exposing CGAL's [alpha shape implementation](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Alpha_shapes_2/Chapter_main.html) to [Python](http://cgal-python.gforge.inria.fr/Manual/CGAL.Alpha_shapes_2.html).

Be aware that parts of CGAL are licensed under the QPL, which means that if you distribute your program, linked to CGAL, you may need to release it under the QPL.  It is fine to keep your code proprietary if you do not redistribute your program code or binaries.

Answer (score 46):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150613035403/http://ambientspatial.net/ddo/?p=143) is what you are looking for.

You can download and test the program:
(in java, under GPL license)

[image]

The paper presenting the algorithm is there:

[Duckham, M., Kulik, L., Worboys, M.F., Galton, A. (2008) Efficient generation of simple polygons for characterizing the shape of a set of points in the plane. Pattern Recognition v41, 3224-3236](http://www.geosensor.net/papers/duckham08.PR.pdf)

Answer (score 37):

This seems to be a specific application of [alpha shapes](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/projects97/belair/alpha.html), which are from my reading a more general form of this problem. R has the [alphahull module](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/alphahull/index.html), which has [excellent documentation on  computing alpha shapes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/alphahull/vignettes/alphahull.pdf). Also check this [detailed background](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~edels/Papers/2010-B-01-AlphaShapes.pdf) on alpha shapes. If you only want to compute convex/concave hulls, check out [lasboundary](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/lasboundary_README.txt), part of [lastools](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/), it scales well and can handle millions of input points.

Finally, this [interesting application of alpha shapes by Flickr](http://code.flickr.com/blog/2008/10/30/the-shape-of-alpha/) made the rounds a while ago, showing their utility for aggregating user generated point content:

[image: alpha hull of texas from flickr]

Answer (score 23):

There is an implementation of ST_ConcaveHull in PostGIS trunk.
http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConcaveHull.html

Answer (score 23):

I created a highly-efficient tool, called **lasboundary** ([1](http://lastools.org/download/lasboundary_README.txt),[2](http://lastools.org/download/lastools.zip)), that computes a concave hull for LIDAR in LAS/LAZ/SHP/ASCII format and stores the result as a vector boundary polygon in ESRI Shapefile format or a geo-referenced KML file.

Here is an example run:

```
C:\lastools\bin>lasboundary -i SerpentMound.las -o SerpentMound_boundary.shp
reading 3265110 points and computing convex hull for 3265110 points
growing inward towards concave hull (with concavity = 50)
outputting the concave hull
concave hull has 1639 points
```

Some result pictures are [here](https://lidarbb.cr.usgs.gov/index.php?showtopic=7799).

Answer (score 13):

Here is an R function that implements the Alpha Hull model. The output is an sp polygon object. Please see the example in the header. It requires the sp, alphahull and maptools packages.

**Update (01-15-2018)
There have been numerous changes to the resulting objects produced by the alphahull package. As such, I needed to rewrite the function. I added a convexHull function to the spatialEco package. However, due to licensing restrictions in the alphahull package this function is only available in the development version on GitHub. The development version can be installed using:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("jeffreyevans/spatialEco")
```

Here is an example of the functions usage

```
library(sp)
library(spatialEco)
data(meuse)
 coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
a <- convexHull(meuse, alpha=100000)
  plot(a)
    points(meuse, pch=19)
```

Convert the resulting SpatialLinesDataFrame to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

```
library(sf)
a <- sf::st_as_sf(a) 
a <- sf::st_polygonize(a)
class( a <- as(a, "Spatial") )
  plot(a)
```

Test multiple alpha values

```
par(mfcol=c(2,2))
   for (a in c(500, 1500, 5000, 100000)) {
   ch <- convexHull(meuse, alpha = a)
     plot(ch)
      points(meuse, pch=19)
        title( paste0("alpha=", a))      
   }
```

[image: various ahull alpha parameter(s)]

Answer (score 11):

JTS (https://github.com/locationtech/jts) provides a Convex Hull implementation. Martin Davies also mentioned having an Alpha Shape algorithm in the works so you might want to check the SVN repository to see if it is in yet if that's what you want.

Answer (score 11):

About R implementation Alpha-Shapes, there's an article about "Converting Alpha-Shapes into SP Objects"

It's based on alphahull, sp and spgrass6
http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/node/919

Answer (score 10):

Speaking about JTS, you can use Geoscript for manipulating JTS library.
http://geoscriptblog.blogspot.com/2010/06/unwrapped-jts-with-python.html for an article about convex hull.
GeoScript implementations are available in JavaScript, Python, Scala, and Groovy.
The official website : http://geoscript.org

Answer (score 10):

Here's a program written in C that computes convex hulls, alpha shapes, Delauney triangluations and Voronoi volumes:

- [Hull](http://www.netlib.org/voronoi/hull.html) - Ken Clarkson (2002)

Another convex hull algorithm with [C](http://maven.smith.edu/~orourke/CGCode/SecondEdition/Ccode2.tar.gz) and [Java](http://maven.smith.edu/~orourke/CGCode/SecondEdition/cgjava.tar.gz) implementations is here:

- Convex Hull (2D) - [Computational Geometry in C](http://maven.smith.edu/~orourke/books/ftp.html), Joseph O'Rourke (1998)

Comment: The second link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 9):

QGIS does have [Concave hull](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#concave-hull-alpha-shapes) algorithm.

> Parameters
> Input point layer [vector: point]
> put parameter description here

> Threshold (0-1, where 1 is equivalent with Convex Hull) [number]
> put parameter description here
> Default: 0.3

> Allow holes [boolean]
> put parameter description here
> Default: True

> Split multipart geometry into singleparts geometries [boolean]
>
> Default: False

> Outputs
> Concave hull [vector]
> put output description here

> Console usage
> processing.runalg('qgis:concavehull', input, alpha, holes, no_multigeometry, output)

Also, Esri has a tool [Minimum Bounding Geometry (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003q000000.htm)

Which allows you to choose the geometry type, which includes convex hull

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To help with the "proper definition" part of your question; you may have looked at
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull and gotten what could well be considered a "proper" definition, but found it lacking, so perhaps a more "useful" definition is:

For **every** point inside a convex hull, a straight line to **any** point not within the hull will only intersect the hull once.

This is useful because given a point you can construct a line through it and test for that constructed line intersecting segments of the hull.

- No intersection the point is not in the hull.
- One intersection the point is on the hull.
- Two intersections the point is within the hull
- A straight line cannot intersect a convex hull more than twice

Comment: the op is asking about concave hulls, and not convex hulls

Answer (score 1):

[JTS](https://github.com/locationtech/jts) now has a [Concave Hull](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jts/algorithm/hull/ConcaveHull.java) implementation.  This is based on erosion of the Delaunay triangulation of the input points.  It supports creating holes, and provides both absolute and scale-free length parameters.

The algorithm has also been ported to [GEOS](http://libgeos.org/), and exposed in the next version (3.3) of [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_ConcaveHull.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you begin with black points drawn on a white plane.

One approach would be to...

> 1. find the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of the [point cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_cloud).
> 2. convert to [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system).
> 3. sort the points based on the angle-part of the polar coordinate.
> 4. draw a [polygonal chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain) with straight line-segments from dot-to-dot.
> 5. fill the inside of the region enclosed by the [polygonal chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain) with pure black.
> 6. observe that the result has a lot of spikes, like a pincushion or a [Japanese Shuriken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuriken)
> 7. Let `maxdist` be the the maximum distance from any point in the point cloud to the center of the point cloud.
> 8. Grow the the selection by `0.25*maxdist` ("grow selection" comes from the open source [GNU image manipulation program](https://www.gimp.org/))
> 9. shrink the the selection by `0.25*maxdist` ("shink selection" comes from the open source [GNU image manipulation program](https://www.gimp.org/)  )

Note that the ***shink*** function is not the inverse of the ***grow*** function. For any shape ***x***, ***shrink(grow(x)) ≠ x***.

Growing the selection removes any valleys or spikes on the surface of the shape, but makes the shape too large.

Shrinking the result from the grow operation will make the shape the correct size again.