# Is there a way to distinguish data precision in KML?

Tags: kml, geocoding, precision

Here's my problem (and I was inspired to ask this from [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5880/how-to-geocode-a-city))...

I create a KML file recording of where upcoming training courses will be for the next year. The cities might be Atlanta, Calgary, Toronto, Dallas, etc

So I can automate the process, I read the list from a file, use a geocoding service to get the coordinates of "Atlanta" and insert a placemark at that point. Now a user can open the KML and see there is training in Atlanta.

However, what if that user zooms right into Google Earth, uses the placemark to identify a particular building, and assumes the training will take place there?

I can't give the exact building location, because it won't be booked till closer to the date. But how do I tell my user that the placemark is only meant to signify position to the city-level, and not right down to a particular building?

Should I fiddle about with zoom-level displays, use a polygon instead of a point, or is there a good KML method to solve the issue?

Comment: Would a description balloon stating the above details not suffice?

Comment: geocode to 6 decimal places in decimal degrees will be accuarate enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO best to approach this from a cartographic viewpoint before thinking about the tech implementation.

**Cartography:** You are quite correct that a polygon makes more sense than a point as you are actually marking an area.  However, a polygon isn't visible from a great altitude, pins (or the point icon you choose) in KML remain constant in size over a certain range in altitude and that is probably helpful to you.  The best combination IMHO would therefore be a point that fades out as the user drops in altitude whilst fadeing in a low opacity polygon with no hard border (gives the user a sense of 'rough region').  I would suggest the polygon to choose is a blue circle as this is what the iPhone uses to show when it is not sure of your location - perfectly sound way to do it and what a number of your users will have seen.  E.g.
http://www.reseo.com/blog/iphone-maps-gps-local-search-results-and-mobile-advertising

**Tech:** The way to do this in KML is regions:
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#region

Create a placemark/polygon pair for each location and program them using regions with an appropriate fade in/out behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Could you use a polygon to identify the area (with a very low opacity level) so that it suggests an area, rather than a specific location?

---

As an aside, [CityGML](http://kugel.bv.tu-berlin.de/typo3-igg/index.php?id=1532) deals with this issue by formalizing Levels of Detail (LODs) for 3D buildings. It's not quite relevant for marking city boundaries (I think) as it focuses more on the building / neighborhood level.