# How can I use Convex Hull to select an area with a space from the points?

Tags: postgis, convex-hull, concave-hull

This refer to this post : [Read Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/concave-hull-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions)

My goal is to select an area covering some points, but maintaining some space from points of border, like in the follow picture :

[image]

I think ST_Convexhull will do the job, but the border will touch the points in the edge.
I need some "tolerance" increasing the area in some way.

Comment: You could buffer the points and get the convex hull of that. Your illustration is more of a concave hull though, much more complicated.

Comment: What if I create big circles around my points and do a ST_ConcaveHull ? This will make a "rubber" in circles that surround my points at the distance I need ... Can somebody explain me how can I do that in PostGIS ?