# How to divide my area into adjacent polygons containing 80 points each?

Tags: qgis, point, clustering

I have a couple of thousand points in my dataset. I need to create clusters that each consists of 80 points. The specific selection of which points to put into a cluster is not critical - only the proximity. From these 80-point clusters I need to create 1 polygon pr. cluster, so I end up with dividing my area into adjacent polygons containing 80 polygons each.

A solution usable in QGIS and other open source tools would be great!

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. This question might be easier to answer if you can tell us a bit more about your data set. For example, telling us what format your data is in might be useful. Also, tell us what other tools and languages you are comfortable using might prevent answers that are of no use to you. You can just edit your question (click "edit" below the question) to add these details and anything else you can think of, such as what you've already tried.

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71078/how-to-merge-close-points-into-polygon