# Creating polygon which outlines many smaller polygons to show their extent using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, aggregation

I am looking at a wildfire, and I need to display the wildfire footprint, however all I have is a raster of classes, I converted that raster to a polygon for values that show low to high burn severity, but now I need to figure out how to turn that into a footprint.  Perhaps something akin to dilation.

How do I do this in ArcMap?

The picture shows the polygons and the blue line is essentially what I am trying to get as output.

[image]

Comment: I don't have access to ArcMap, but using QGIS, I would try creating a concave hull. This should be possible ni ArcMap as well, I guess.

Comment: Your blue line is an imaginary line. Still, try a concave hull. Here is some more information:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/what-are-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions-for-concave-hull

Comment: Convert your raster to points and play with kernel density, I.e. different search radius and threshold in output, that you want to classify into 2 categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested use of kernel density and I think this is a right approach, because it gives you something objective:

[image]

It seems that you have more than 1 fire.