# Combining non-contiguous polygons in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, merge, dissolve

[image]

I am trying to combine non-contiguous polygons that are close but not touching one shape. As if you were to draw a line around these five parts connecting them into one. Originally these were part of a multipart feature that I exploded. I have tried merge (which combines the features but does not dissolve the boundary physically), aggregate, and dissolve. I have hundreds of shapes to do this with but I attached a screenshot of five polygons as an example.

Comment: Does Eliminate tool give you good solution?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like the **[concave hull](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/what-are-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions-for-concave-hull)** of these shapes.

Your best option for ArcGIS Pro appears to be the [Minimum Bounding Geometry tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm). The issue here may be that this only outputs *convex* hulls rather than *concave* hulls. (I haven't tested the tool myself so  I can't be sure that it won't work for your situation).

I also found reference to [a suite of community tools](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-blog/concave-hulls-the-elusive-container/ba-p/902545) that might work.

If you have access to PostGIS, [ST_ConcavHull](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConcaveHull.html) should achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [Snap (Editing)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/editing/snap.htm) tool.  Pick a maximum distance that polygons can be apart before they're considered separate, that is used in the snap environment distance parameter. Note you may wish to use the [Densify (Editing)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/editing/densify.htm) tool first to add some extra vertices (with a distance less than the maximum snap distance).

Note that both Densify and Snap **modify** the input data, so make a backup or run the tools on a copy of the data.

You can then dissolve if you like.

E.g.

**Input:**

[image]

**Densify:**

[image]

**Snap:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Dissolved:**

[image]