# Create the smallest-possible polygon that encompasses all points within Python

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, concave-hull

I'm working with a DataFrame that has a few thousand coordinate points and am plotting them using `plotly.express`. I want to draw a marker around the perimeter of the points that encompasses all of the points. I've been using `geopandas` and the `convex_hull` function, but it doesn't seem to return the smallest possible polygon.

For example, here's what I have so far:

[image]

The black line represents a tracer that was added using `go.Scattermapbox` to connect the points of the smallest possible polygon selected using the `convex_hull` function. However, as we can see, it doesn't appear to be the smallest possible polygon? There's a lot of space that is open that could be removed to make the polygon smaller.

Here's the code I've been working with in terms of the `convex_hull` function:

```
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(points, crs=crs)
convex_points = geo_df.unary_union.convex_hull
convex_coords = list(convex_points.exterior.coords)
convex_coords = pd.DataFrame(convex_coords, columns=['lon','lat'])
```

where the `points` variable is a DataFrame filled with `geometry` points that were created using the `Point` function within `shapely`.

Am I missing something with `convex_hull`? Is this truly the smallest possible polygon that the function can return? And if so, is there another option to use to get a smaller possible polygon?

Comment: Convex hull gives the smallest *convex* polygon. You need to look into *concave* polygons instead. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/what-are-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions-for-concave-hull

Comment: What you are looking for is called  [Concave hull](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/what-are-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions-for-concave-hull). or  [Alpha shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape) and there are answers in GSE